# Using `pam_access` with `substack` errors

Tags: ssh, pam

I am implementing [`pam_duo`](https://duo.com/docs/duounix) for multifactor authentication for SSH on a Redhat 9 system, but I want to only require it when the user is outside the network.

The file `/etc/security/access-duo.conf` contains the IP addresses that I want to have different rules for.

```
+ : ALL : 192.0.2.0/24 10.0.0.0/8
- : ALL : ALL
```

Users are authenticating with Kerberos, using SSSD. The `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` is the stock configuration set by `authselect`.

```
# Generated by authselect on Thu Jun 23 14:34:23 2022
# Do not modify this file manually.

auth        required                                     pam_env.so
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient                                   pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        sufficient                                   pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required                                     pam_deny.so

[[Other types - account/password/session]]
```

I copied these rules and made two modifications for `pam_duo`:

```
auth        required                                     pam_env.so
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient                                   pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        requisite                                    pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        sufficient                                   pam_duo.so
auth        required                                     pam_deny.so
```

The change is `pam_sss` is now `requisite` and `pam_duo` is added and is `sufficient`.

I modified `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to skip rules based on `pam_access`:

```
auth       [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-duo.conf
auth       substack                        password-auth-duo
auth       [success=ignore default=1]      pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-duo.conf
auth       substack                        password-auth
auth       include                         postlogin
```

When I try to connect with SSH, I am able to successfully authenticate and a Duo prompt is only shown if I am connecting from outside the network, but then the SSH connection is suddenly closed and the server logs the error in `/var/log/secure`:

```
sshd[94170]: fatal: PAM: pam_setcred(): The return value should be ignored by PAM dispatch
```

I have also tried with the exact same content in `/etc/pam.d/password-auth-duo` and  `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` and I still have this issue, so it isn't Duo related.

If I copy all the rules from the substack into `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, everything works, but it makes the files difficult to read, so I would like to keep them separate.

I found very few results in a search for this error - most of them are pretty old and don't have obvious implications for my situation.

What am I missing? Is this a configuration issue or a PAM bug?